# Can't use value in different classes

Tags: java, coordinate

I know how to put value from one class to another.
Just here it doesn't work. I can't understand why.

Please help me to find a bug.

When I try to get value:

```
 c = new CartesianCoordinate(x, y);
 x = c.getX();
```

It is always zero.

```
public class Velocity
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private double x;
    private double y;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Velocity
     */
    public Velocity(CartesianCoordinate c)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);
        x = c.getX();
        System.out.println(c.getX());
        System.out.println(c.getY());
        System.out.println(c.x);

     }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
```

Here is my CartesianCoordinate:

```
    public class CartesianCoordinate
    {
       // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
       public double x;
       public double y;

       /**
        * Constructor for objects of class CartesianCoordinate
        */
       public CartesianCoordinate(double x, double y)
       {
           // initialise instance variables
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
       }




    public void setX(double x)
    {
        // put your code here
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(double y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);` shadows the parameter you're passing -- is this your intention?

Comment: In the example code you have given, no values are ever assigned to x and y of the constructor call 'new CartesianCoordinate(x,y)'. Side remark: The instance variables in CartesianCoordinate ought to be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following line:

```
c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);
```

you are creating a new instance with the values of `Velocity` instance private fields `x` and `y`, which are set to 0 by default.

By the way, it makes no sense to pass a `CartesianCoordinate` instance as the constructor parameter, then re-initialising it inside the constructor itself. Either you pass `x` and `y` values like `public Velocity(int x, int y)`, or you just assign the coordinate.

In the future, you'll want to know about [`Point2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) class.

Answer (score 4):

```
public Velocity(CartesianCoordinate c)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);   // 1
    x = c.getX();                       // 2
    System.out.println(c.getX());       // 3
    System.out.println(c.getY());       // 4
    System.out.println(c.x);            // 5
 }
```

On line 1 you shadow the parameter you're passing.  Meaning you're "overwriting" the value of `c` with a brand new `CartesianCoordinate` initialized with `x` and `y`, which, at that point, are both 0 (since you haven't initialized the doubles).

If you remove line 1, you'll at least get the `x` of the `CartesianCoordinate` you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

`c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);`
This constructor call is assigning `x = 0` and `y = 0` for member variables `x` and `y` of `CartesianCoordinate` class.This is so because within `Velocity` class `x` and `y` are provided with default value `0` as you have never changed it. So you are getting `0` for `c.getX()` and `c.getY()`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

c = new CartesianCoordinate(x,y);

from Velocity constructor

Answer (score 0):

x,y variables have not been initialized so you always receive 0